# Rails: remove certain HTML tags only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a string that looks like this:

```
<h3>Some title</h3>
Blah blah blah string I want to keep
<br>
```

And I want to return only this part, removing the `<h3>...</h3>`:

```
Blah blah blah string I want to keep
```

What regex would I need? I presently have this method but it returns the content of `<h3>`.

```
def remove_all_html(string)
  sanitize(string, tags: {}).gsub(/&nbsp;/i, ' ')
end
```

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well:

```
def hide_headings_and_sanitize(string)
  string.slice!(/(<h3>.*<\/h3>)/)
  sanitize(string, tags: {}).gsub(/&nbsp;/i, ' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If its always going to be a simple case like that

```
def remove_all_html(string)
  string.gsub!(/<\w*>(\w*|\s*)*<\/\w*>/, "") # remove any complete tags
  string.gsub!(/<\w*(\s|\/)*>/, "") # remove any standalone or self closing tags
end
```

should suffice